# Exclude from file if line contains value from variable A OR B

Tags: powershell

I am writing to a file using streamwriter and I want to exclude any rows that match the values containing in two parameters. I have tried the below code but it does not output any values when I include the second condition (`$file_stream -notmatch $exclude_permission_type`).

```
$exclude_user_accounts = 'account1', 'account2', 'account3' 
$exclude_permission_type = 'WRITE'

while ($file_stream = $report_input.ReadLine()) {
  if ($file_stream -notmatch $exclude_user_accounts -and $file_stream -notmatch $exclude_permission_type) { 
    $_report_output.WriteLine($file_stream)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please show sample input, the desired output, and the values for `$exclude_user_accounts` and `$exclude_permission_type` that are supposed to produce that output.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - added.

Comment: That is only half of what I was asking for. Please provide the other information as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly not possible that your code has ever worked the way you intended, even with just the first condition, because a string can never match an array of strings . `<string> -notmatch <array>` will always evaluate to `true` even if the array contained an exact match. You cannot do partial matches like that at all.

Build one regular expression from all your filter strings:

```
$excludes = 'account1', 'account2', 'account3', 'WRITE'

$re = ($excludes | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
```

then filter your strings using that regular expression:

```
if ($file_stream -notmatch $re) {
    $_report_output.WriteLine($file_stream)
}
```